# Ajax Cascade Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am trying to create cascade dropdownlist using ajax. So when user selects the degree dropdown, the second dropdown box displays schools that offer that selected degree. But for some reasons, my ajax $("#degreeid").on("change",function(){}); does not get called. Not sure why. Help please!

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  <div id="select-degree-form">
    <div">
      <span id="Label1">Degree List</span> &nbsp; @Html.DropDownList("degreeid", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DegreeList, "Select a Degree")
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="select-school-form">
    <div">
      <span id="Label1">School List</span><select id="SecondDropdown"></select>
    </div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

     <script>
      $("#degreeid").on("change", function () {
        showValue($(this).val());
      });

      function showValue(val) {
        console.log(val);
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetDropdownList", "Home")' + "?value=" + val, function (result) {
          $("#SecondDropdown").html(""); // makes select null before filling process
          var data = result.data;
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("#schoollist").append("<option>" + data[i] + "</option>")
          }
        })
      }
    </script>
  </div>
<!-- MORE CODE -->
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetDropdownList(int? value)
{
  using (DataModel db = new DataModel())
  {
    var qry = (from a in db.schools where a.degree_id == value && a.active == true
                           select new
                           {
                               institution_id = a.institution_id,
                               institution_name = b.institution_name

                           }).Distinct();

    List<string> institutionList = new List<string>();
    foreach(var item in qry)
    {
        institutionList.Add(item.institution_name);
    }

    return Json(new { data = institutionList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding your script to `on ready` function:

change this:

```
$("#degreeid").on("change", function () {
    showValue($(this).val());
});
```

For this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#degreeid").on("change", function () {
    showValue($(this).val());
  });
});
```

And change this:

```
function showValue(val) {
  console.log(val);
  $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetDropdownList", "Home")' + "?value=" + val, function (result) {
    $("#SecondDropdown").html(""); // makes select null before filling process
    var data = result.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      $("#schoollist").append("<option>" + data[i] + "</option>")
    }
  })
}
```

For this:

```
function showValue(val) {
  console.log(val);
  $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetDropdownList", "Home")' + "?value=" + val, function (result) {
    $("#SecondDropdown").html(""); // makes select null before filling process
    var data = result.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      $("#schoollist").append("<option value=" + data[i]["institution_id"] + ">" + data[i]["institution_name"] + "</option>")
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it still did not call the first function. $(function(){
  $("#degreeid").on("change", function () {
    showValue($(this).val());
  });
});

Comment: Try moving the bootstrap references and all the scripts to the top, maybe the resources are no loaded in time